# SOLR Connect to external MongoDB instance using DIH (Data import Handler)

Tags: mongodb, solr

I am looking for configuring full-text search using Apache SOLR, I am using MongoDB as database.

I am able to make successful connection between local MongoDB and local Apache SOLR using mongo drivers with Data import handlers.

However when I try to connect to the remote database from my local SOLR instance it is not allowing the connection.

Here is the error I am getting. Can anyone help me with this?

```
null:java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.mongodb.DB.authenticate(Ljava/lang/String;[C)Z
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.sendError(HttpSolrCall.java:663)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.call(HttpSolrCall.java:531)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:395)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:341)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1602)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:540)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1588)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1345)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:480)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1557)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1247)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:144)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:220)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:126)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.RewriteHandler.handle(RewriteHandler.java:335)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:502)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:364)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:260)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:305)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:333)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:310)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:168)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:126)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:366)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:765)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:683)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.mongodb.DB.authenticate(Ljava/lang/String;[C)Z
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.MongoDataSource.init(MongoDataSource.java:57)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.getDataSourceInstance(DataImporter.java:397)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.ContextImpl.getDataSource(ContextImpl.java:100)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.MongoEntityProcessor.init(MongoEntityProcessor.java:33)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.EntityProcessorWrapper.init(EntityProcessorWrapper.java:77)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.buildDocument(DocBuilder.java:434)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.buildDocument(DocBuilder.java:415)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.doFullDump(DocBuilder.java:330)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.execute(DocBuilder.java:233)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.doFullImport(DataImporter.java:424)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.runCmd(DataImporter.java:483)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler.handleRequestBody(DataImportHandler.java:184)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:199)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:2551)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.execute(HttpSolrCall.java:710)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.call(HttpSolrCall.java:516)
    ... 36 more
```

Comment: Would you please check, if the Version of your MongoDB server and MongoDB drivers within Solr are compatible? Other problems with this matter were solved due to version conflicts (driver version of the client vs installed version on the server).

Comment: I was able to fix it by updating the mongo importer connector Jar file.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if the Version of your MongoDB server and MongoDB drivers within Solr are compatible? Other problems with this matter were solved due to version conflicts (driver version of the client vs installed version on the server).